# Need to fill a sheet with consecutive rows data based on value in another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

OK here's the situation.  I've created a workbook with 5 sheets in it.

The first sheet has columns for QTY, DESCRIPTION, PRICE and some other data, but those are the pertinent ones.

Based on the data entered, a labor invoice and several order forms are filled out.  That is working correctly.

The issue I am having is I also need it to fill out a sheet named Contract.  There are approximately 75 items on the main sheet, but the contract will never have more than 30 items.

I need to pull over only rows that have a non-zero value for QTY on the main sheet to the contract sheet, consecutively so that there are no blank rows until the data-set runs out of items with non zero QTY on the main sheet.

`I.E.` if there are 15 non-consecutive rows on the main sheet with non-zero values for QTY, on the Contract sheet I need the first 15 rows out of 30 to pull over QTY, DESCRIPTION, PRICE from the main worksheet rows with non-zero QTY values.

I hope I am making sense.. It's got me stumped!

Thanks

EDIT:  I just realized, I need to only pull data that has non zero values for QTY AND Contract Cost to the contract sheet! oops!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I assumed that you need pull data from main to contract. I hope i get your question right 
Main worksheet :
[image: Main Worksheet]

Contract worksheet (Result)

[image: Contract Worksheet]

```
Option Explicit
Dim MyWorkbook As Workbook
Dim MyWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim MyOutputWorksheet As Worksheet

Sub PullData()
Set MyWorkbook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
Set MyWorksheet = MyWorkbook.Sheets("Main")
Set MyOutputWorksheet = MyWorkbook.Sheets("Contract")

    Dim myValue As Long
    Dim RowPointer As Long

    For RowPointer = 2 To MyWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        If MyWorksheet.Range("A" & RowPointer).Value > 0 And MyWorksheet.Range("A" & RowPointer).Value <> "" Then
            If MyOutputWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row > 15 Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
            MyWorksheet.Range(("A" & RowPointer) & ":C" & RowPointer).Copy Destination:=MyOutputWorksheet.Range("A" & MyOutputWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        End If
    Next RowPointer


End Sub
```

Comment: I just realized, I need to only pull data that has non zero values for QTY AND Contract Cost to the contract sheet! oops!

Comment: I see where  I would add and AND to the IF statement to verify a non-zero value for contract cost, that's great!  Do I just add a macro button and use this code then?

Comment: Yes, you just need add a button and assign macro to the button than it will work.

Comment: That code looks great, the one thing I didn't mention, the output rows do not contain all the data of the input rows.  So I need to output only certian columns.  Also I need them to inport to certian rows and columns on the second sheet, the Contract sheet.  Column A on the Main sheet goes to column A starting at row 17.  B to B , E to D  F to E all starting at row 17 on the Contract sheet.

Comment: If you need import certain rows to the second sheet (Contract worksheet) , you need have the rules (_e.g. item name contains certain characters/word, that row must be imported and it always located at row 17 of Main worksheet, and etc_) for the certain rows to write them as code logic in macro, else I would suggest that manually copy will be a better solution in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following screenshot. The left is the "Main" sheet, on the right is the "Contract" sheet.

[image]

Cell A2 on the "Contract" sheet has the formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Main!A:A,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(Main!$A$1:$A$10)*(Main!$A$1:$A$10>0),ROW(Main!$A$1:$A$10),""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then copy down and across.

Adjust cell references to reflect your scenario. Use ranges with row numbers. Don't use whole column references with array formulas.

Edit: to return only rows where in addition to existing conditions the cost is greater than 0, use this formula, also array-entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Main!A:A,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(Main!$A$1:$A$10)*(Main!$A$1:$A$10>0)*(Main!$c$1:$c$10>0),ROW(Main!$A$1:$A$10),""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

Comment: I just realized, I need to only pull data that has non zero values for QTY AND Contract Cost to the contract sheet! oops!

Comment: Can I and an AND to the IF statement to determine if the the contract price is greater than zero in the same manner that it determines if the qty is greater than zero?

Comment: I added a formula that will do that.

Comment: I'm a bit behind on this, but after implementing all of the solutions on the page [thanks everyone!] I realized I needed to add a few more conditions!      So I need to output only certain columns. Also I need them to inport to certain rows and columns on the second sheet, the CONTRACT sheet. Column A on the MAIN sheet goes to column A starting at row 17 on the CONTRACT sheet. B to B , E to D, F to E, all starting at row 17 on the CONTRACT sheet. Rows 17-42 on the CONTRACT sheet will contain data.

Comment: Whoa. Hold your horses. You've just changed the game completely. That's like ordering a VW Beetle, and then adding all the features of a Lamborghini. Stick to your original question. Mark the answer to that original question. That was the playing field and you should not change that. If you have a follow up question, or if your circumstances change, you can ask a new question at no additional cost. Maybe this time you want to think about your REAL requirements before you send folks on a wild goose chase and then bow out without an upvote or an answer marking.

Comment: Fair enough.  Answer marked, new question asked, and thanks for your help!

Comment: How's this for an on-topic question?  How do I modify the formula to fill rows 1-30 and use columns A-F

Comment: and check columns A and E for the non-zero values?  When I try to just input the formula as given, I get an error "you can not change part of an array" when I go to copy it to the other cells.  I am using Excel 2010 BTW

Comment: OK sorry about all the BS.  I have all my data transfer stuff worked out, to get what I want where I want it.  Unfortunately the formula isn't quite working correctly.  I need it to check columns A and E for non-zero values.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but if you want to do it in a macro, I believe something like this would work:

```
Sub test()
'
' test Macro
'

'
    Dim i As Integer
    Range("A:A").Select
    i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Selection) + 1
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Dim numZero As Integer
    numZero = 0
    Dim temp As Integer
    For j = 2 To i
        temp = Range("Sheet1!A" & j).Value
        If temp = 0 Then
            numZero = numZero + 1
        Else
            Range("A" & j - numZero).Select
            Selection.Formula = "=IF(Sheet1!A" & j & "<> 0, Sheet1!A" & j & ",FALSE)"
            Range("B" & j - numZero).Select
            Selection.Value = "=Sheet1!B" & j
            Range("C" & j - numZero).Select
            Selection.Value = "=Sheet1!C" & j
        End If
    Next j
End Sub
```

This is not the cleanest macro cause I threw it together quick but it gets the job done and should be fast enough if your data isn't gigantic.

Comment: I just realized, I need to only pull data that has non zero values for QTY AND Contract Cost to the contract sheet! oops!

Comment: Can I add another veriable that holds th data from the contract price cells, and say IF temp=0 OR temp2=0 then numZero=numZero+1 clause to the statement?

Comment: Yes, that should work. you'd want to set _temp2 = Range("Sheet1!D" &j).Value_ That is assuming column D holds the Contract Cost

Comment: I'm a bit behind on this, but after implementing all of the solutions on the page [thanks everyone!] I realized I needed to add a few more conditions!      So I need to output only certain columns. Also I need them to inport to certain rows and columns on the second sheet, the CONTRACT sheet. Column A on the MAIN sheet goes to column A starting at row 17 on the CONTRACT sheet. B to B , E to D, F to E, all starting at row 17 on the CONTRACT sheet. Rows 17-42 on the CONTRACT sheet will contain data.