# Need to transpose rows while transferring data from one excel sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

My original question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656997/need-to-fill-a-sheet-with-consecutive-rows-data-based-on-value-in-another-worksh).

Basically I needed some help transferring data from one sheet to another based on values in the first sheet.  I am using a modified bit of code provided by user [keong kenshih](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4967653/keong-kenshih).

I added an additional check against another row to the `IF` statement, and I have this for my code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim MyWorkbook As Workbook
Dim MyWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim MyOutputWorksheet As Worksheet
```

So I need to output only certain columns. Also I need them to import to certain rows and columns on the second sheet, the CONTRACT sheet. Column A on the MAIN sheet goes to column A starting at row 17 on the CONTRACT sheet. B to B , E to D, F to E, all starting at row 17 on the CONTRACT sheet.
Rows 17-42 on the CONTRACT sheet will contain data.

```
Sub PullData()
    Set MyWorkbook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
    Set MyWorksheet = MyWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN")
    Set MyOutputWorksheet = MyWorkbook.Sheets("CONTRACT")

    Dim myValue As Long
    Dim RowPointer As Long

    For RowPointer = 6 To MyWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        If MyWorksheet.Range("A" & RowPointer).V  alue > 0 And 
        MyWorksheet.Range("A" & RowPointer).Value <> "" 
        MyWorksheet.Range("F" & RowPointer).Value > 0 And 
        MyWorksheet.Range("F" & RowPointer).Value <> ""Then
            If MyOutputWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row > 15 
            Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
            MyWorksheet.Range(("A" & RowPointer) & ":C" & RowPointer).Copy 
            Destination:=MyOutputWorksheet.Range("A" & 
            MyOutputWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        End If
    Next RowPointer
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI* Slight spacing issue in your If statement

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try :

```
Sub PullData()

Dim wRow As Long, _
    RowPointer As Long, _
    MyWorkbook As Workbook, _
    Ws As Worksheet, _
    OutWs As Worksheet

Set MyWorkbook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
Set Ws = MyWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN")
Set OutWs = MyWorkbook.Sheets("CONTRACT")

With Ws
    For RowPointer = 6 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        If .Range("A" & RowPointer).Value > 0 And _
                .Range("A" & RowPointer).Value <> "" And _
                .Range("F" & RowPointer).Value > 0 And _
                .Range("F" & RowPointer).Value <> "" Then
            'This line would get you out of the loop after the first copy because _
            'You first paste on line 17 and then the below left part will be equal to 18
            'If OutWs.Cells(OutWs.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row > 15 Then Exit Sub


            wRow = OutWs.Rows(OutWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            'Always start copy after (or at) line 17
            If wRow <= 17 Then wRow = 17
            'More efficient way to copy data between ranges
            OutWs.Range("A" & wRow).Value = Ws.Range("A" & RowPointer)
            OutWs.Range("B" & wRow).Value = Ws.Range("B" & RowPointer)
            OutWs.Range("D" & wRow).Value = Ws.Range("E" & RowPointer)
            OutWs.Range("E" & wRow).Value = Ws.Range("F" & RowPointer)
        End If
    Next RowPointer
End With

Set MyWorkbook = Nothing
Set Ws = Nothing
Set OutWs = Nothing

End Sub
```